# csharp to java JNI porting call to run on ubuntu

Tags: c#, java, ubuntu, managed-c++

I getting bug: *crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code*. whenever i run with class file  with native library and .net module file it works fine.
but when i try to run alone class file and native library it gets crash .please clarify my mistake i have done, please review my code. 
for your reference with parameter

==========================================

```
 public class Sum
    {
        public int add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
```

===========================================

save as Sum.cs and compile it to module
using cmd:

> *csc /t:module sum.cs*

Create Java File to test

===========================================

```
public class test{
public native int add(int a,int b);
 static {
        System.loadLibrary("JSample");
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
       System.out.println(new test().add(10,15));
    }
}
```

==========================================

save it as test.java compile as

> *javac test.java*

create native header file

> *javah -jni test*

it will create test.h

create win32 project using visual studio (I used VS2010)
Choose project name as JSample

include header and C#.net module
write header for manged C++ conversion

==============================================

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using "Sum.netmodule"
using namespace System;
public __gc class SumC
{
public:
    Sum __gc *t;
    SumC()
    {
        t = new Sum();          
    }
    int callCSharpSum(int a,int b)
    {
        return  t->add(a,b);
    }
};
```

===========================================

save it as sum.h

create sum.cpp file

============================================

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "test.h"
#include "sum.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_test_add
    (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint a, jint b)
{
    SumC* t = new SumC();  
    return t->callCSharpSum(a ,b );
}
```

=============================================

optimize compiler to build /clr:oldSyntax
Include Jdk/Include directory path
build the project.
we will Get JSample DLL

run the project
with C#.net module,Native DLL file and class file at the same folder.

> *java test*

25

but whenever i run the code with **dll file and class file alone**.
it shows bug report  The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
please clarify how to port managed code C# into C++ (Win32 Un-Managed code). library file.

Comment: To simplify your example, you don't need to create (or free) objects anywhere. I only have a Linux which works so I have not idea what your error is, perhaps you can post a short summary so everyone will know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use .NET assemblies from Java, I strongly suggest you look at IKVM, which is a Java VM that bridges to .NET Runtime.

I've used this back in (I think) 2004 for production software and it worked nicely. The project is actively maintained and recieves support for .NET 4 and Java 7 these days.

You have a choice of

- running the Java code in IKVM so you can use .NET libraries
- run a .NET program that loads java libraries (e.g. jars)

Both ways, there is a preprocessing step to translate the jars to DLLS or viceversa.

See http://ikvm.net

Comment: thanks to reply sehe ,but my  aim on this make .net manged code to complete un managed code(pure win32 library)  that is capable to run on win32 system without .net run time environment. ubuntu is my secondary so far .so file only normally works over linux based system.

Comment: @arunkumarnonascii: I don't know what you are trying to say, but IKVM _and_ Mono (.NET) run perfectly on Linux. I have run the entire eclipse IDE on IKVM on linux to use managed code from Eclipse Plugins... I used Ubuntu almost exclusively, myself